# SQLAlchemy: how to filter on field several relationships deep?

Tags: sqlalchemy

I have a hierarchical DB structure and I would like to make a query with filter on a field that is several levels (relations) deep.

Here is sample of the class declarations:

```
class cTransfer(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mesTransfer'
    transferID = Column(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    quanID = Column(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, ForeignKey('mesQuantum.quanID'))
    quanObj = relationship('cQuantum', foreign_keys=[quanID], lazy='joined')

class cQuantum(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mesQuantum'
    quanID = Column(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    orderItemID = Column(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, ForeignKey('mesOrderItem.orderItemID'))
    orderItemObj = relationship('cOrderItem', foreign_keys=[orderItemID], lazy='joined')

class cOrderItem(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'mesOrderItem'
    orderItemID = Column(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, primary_key=True, autoincrement=False)
    orderID = Column(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, ForeignKey('mesOrderHeader.orderID'))
    orderHeaderObj = relationship('cOrderHeader', foreign_keys=[orderID], lazy='joined')
```

I would like to fetch all cTransfer whose associated orderID are in some list.

So I tried to do this:

```
q = session.query(cTransfer).filter(cTransfer.quanObj.orderItemObj.orderID.in_([1, 2]))
```

I get an exception: "Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with cTransfer.quanObj has an attribute 'orderItemObj'"

How can I do such query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Below should help. Basically, you need to perform `join`s through all the levels:

```
orderIDs = [1, 2]
q = (session.query(cTransfer)
     .join(cTransfer.quanObj)
     .join(cQuantum.orderItemObj)
     .filter(cOrderItem.orderID.in_(orderIDs))
     .options(contains_eager(cTransfer.quanObj).contains_eager(cQuantum.orderItemObj))
     )
```

*The `options` line hints to `sqlalchemy` that the relationships are already loaded so that it does not add additional `JOIN`s to the `SQL` to the `joined`-loaded relationships.*